# Is SharedCache ready for production?

Tags: .net, asp.net, performance, distributed-caching

I've been comparing distributed caching solutions for an ASP.NET environment and would like to use something FOSS if possible.  I've come across [SharedCache](http://www.codeplex.com/SharedCache) and seen it recommended by a few people on StackOverflow.

Has anyone actually used this in a production environment?  I can't find much online about the maturity of this project and would like to know of anyone's successes or failures with using it.

To be clear, the environment would be a handful of servers (~10 or so), but at least 10GB of cached data to share amongst those servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a bit of a late response, and you've probably solved this a long time ago, but I was wondering the same thing myself...

We used a windows port of memcached for a recent project where we need an out of process cache shared between a site, and a bunch of WCF services in separate App Pools. All was working well for us for a while, but more recently our memcached .net client is reporting failures when we write to the cache. We're not sure what is causing it, but I'm uneasy about running memcached on windows, and looked into "pure" .net solutions. Which is when I found SharedCache.net

Although we haven't swapped over on our production server, I've been using it on a few dev boxes for a while now, and find it good so far - no weird write errors (although to be fair I've not properly load tested it) and it has better features for example for listing the contents of the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Shared Cache in a production environment under heavy load without any major problems.  The only issues I've had with it is that the documentation is lacking and when the cache service is started sometimes the first few entries in the cache were not saved properly but would still contain a key reference....granted this would only happen on a system reboot so it's a minor issue.